# 5.1 surround sound

Tags: sound

Ok, So I’ve always had trouble with enabling 5.1 in Ubuntu. 
Running `alsamixer`:

I have: Master, Headphones, PCM, Front, Front Mi, Front Mi, Surround, Center.
All are at 100%

Card:HDA Intel

Chip:Realtek ALC888 (This is my onboard sound, Its a dell studio, with 7.1 integrated sound)

Running `speaker-test -c6 -twav` I only get the front 2 speakers (Right/Left) making any noise. The others make no noise at all.

I have no other sound card to use as all my PCI slots are used up.

`Daemon.conf`:

```
; daemonize = no
; fail = yes
; allow-module-loading = yes
; allow-exit = yes
; use-pid-file = yes
; system-instance = no
; enable-shm = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB
; lock-memory = no
; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes
; nice-level = -11

; realtime-scheduling = yes
; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20
; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes
; default-script-file = 

; log-target = auto
; log-level = notice
; log-meta = no
; log-time = no
; log-backtrace = 0

resample-method = speex-float-1
; enable-remixing = yes
; enable-lfe-remixing = no

flat-volumes = no

; rlimit-fsize = -1
; rlimit-data = -1
; rlimit-stack = -1
; rlimit-core = -1
; rlimit-as = -1
; rlimit-rss = -1
; rlimit-nproc = -1
; rlimit-nofile = 256
; rlimit-memlock = -1
; rlimit-locks = -1
; rlimit-sigpending = -1
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1
; rlimit-nice = 31
; rlimit-rtprio = 9
; rlimit-rttime = 1000000

; default-sample-format = s16le
; default-sample-rate = 44100
; default-sample-channels = 6
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right

default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
```

Comment: Could help if you make your question a little more detailed than saying "OMFG this works better in windows!!".

What does your setting looks like?

Is your hardware shown correctly in the sound preferences menu?

Comment: Please see the comments on the answers and update the question with new information.

Comment: @tutuca - Alright calm down. It was just meant as a joke.
@Li Lo - Will do.

Comment: In the "Output" tab of Sound Preferences do you have a connector like in this image? http://imgur.com/CIdor.png

Comment: No, It looks like this: http://yfrog.com/5nselection001p
By The way, Does this look right: "default-channel-map = front-left,front-right" Surely there should be rear-right center etc?

Comment: The default-channel-map setting looks to be commented out (because it has ";" at the start of the line so it shouldn't mess up things. Post screenshots of the alsamixer (GNOME Alsa Mixer) and all other sound setting related apps that you can.

Or it might be that the model of the soundcard (there are many HDA Intel models) is wrongly autodetected. Try researching this.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this in terminal:

```
sudo alsamixer
```

You should see separate "volume" sections (eg, Front, Line-In, Center/LFE, etc) that you can mute and unmute (pressing the 'm' key) or change the volume with the arrow keys.

If that doesn't work, then would you gladly clarify if you have a sound card (other than your motherboards sound). :D

Comment: Doesn't work, Its set as 5.1 in the "Sound" menu and all the channels are turned up fully in alsamixer. Using "speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -l1 -twav" I can only hear the front left and right and in daemon.conf the default-sample-channels=6. I do have an audigy SB but the pci slot is taken up by my 9800gt...
Thanks

Comment: Try "speaker-test -c6 -twav" i.e. without selecting the device.

Comment: ONly the front 2 work again. No sound in any of the others

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Select `sound preferences` from sound indicator menu, go to hardware tab and select the applicable surround option from the profile menu.

If all goes well, you should have a working 5.1 sound.

Comment: Yep, that doesn't work ;)

Comment: What, exactly, doesn't work. How does it behave?

Comment: Also which application are you trying to use to access the 5.1 sound?